# MySQL View to show rows from multiple columns in a single column

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I need to create a MySQL View that allows me to show in a single columns all rows from different tables' columns.

For example:
Table1:

```
  -----------------
  | name  |  desc |
  -----------------
1 | name1 | desc1 |
  -----------------
```

Table2:

```
  -----------------
  | name  |  desc |
  -----------------
1 | name2 | desc2 |
  -----------------
```

I would like to have a view that shows:

```
  ---------
  | name  | 
  ---------
1 | name1 |
2 | name2 |
  ---------
```

Is this possible? I only see people using concat() and I don't need this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want `union`/`union all`?

```
select name
from table1
union all
select name
from table2;
```

Comment: I don't know, what would be the result? Maybe it's exactly what I need